# Tool for recovering deleted data from a flash drive

Tags: software-recommendation, usb-drive, data-recovery

What is the best tool for recovering deleted data from a flash drive (pen drive)?

Comment: How did you delete the data? What did you do AFTER you deleted them?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

1. [**TestDisk**](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk_Download)

> find lost partitions and data for
>   External and Internal Drive for all of
>   these file systems, ext2, ext3, ext4
>   and encrypted partition. for windows
>   FAT12/FAT16/FAT32 and NTFS boot
>   sector.

**For Recovering data from external Hard drive**
Type `testdisk` on your terminal and follow this well written step [TestDisk Step-By-Step](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk_Step_By_Step)

**For Recovering files from internal and External hard drives** there is [PhotoRec](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec) which comes with TestDisk.

type `photorec` on your terminal

[image]

Select your drive and hit enter to proceed and follow the instruction.

2. [Extundelete](http://extundelete.sourceforge.net/)

   > extundelete is a utility that can
   >   recover deleted files from an ext3 or
   >   ext4 partition

Comment: PhotoRec is not just for internal hard drives. I regularly use it to recover files from corrupted flash drives.

Comment: I used PhotoRec to recover deleted photos from my camera sd card! This was a life saver as it was a very important occasion and there were over 300 pictures that just went poof!

Answer (score 26):

The Ubuntu Wiki has an [excellent page on Data recovery](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DataRecovery).

I've recently used the command line tool `foremost` for recovering 9000 photos off a SD card.

1. Install foremost: `sudo apt-get install foremost`
2. Mount and create the target directory for storing recovered data, make sure it's large enough to hold the data. I assume it's located at `/media/backup/recover` now.
3. Assuming your flash drive to be named `/dev/sdb`, run:

   ```
   sudo foremost -i /dev/sdb -o /media/backup/recover
   ```
4. Do something else, it might take a while to read and recover the data over USB.

(source: [DataRecovery - Foremost](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DataRecovery#Foremost))

Comment: Thanks! This one worked for me, unlike `recoverjpeg` which recovered only about one third of files, for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

`recoverjpeg` works perfectly for a formatted USB disk / thumb drive.

1. Install recoverjpeg: sudo apt-get install recoverjpeg -y
2. Recover the pics

   $ sudo recoverjpeg /dev/sdc -o ~/recover_usb/

   Restored 1056 pictures