# dual boot Windows 8 and Ubuntu (Partition not detecting)

Tags: dual-boot

I have installed Windows 8 and disabled secure boot. when trying to install Ubuntu in "something else" option of disk partition. It shows only one hard disk with full free space (500 GB) , no windows partition. the windows partition is 300 GB and free space is 200 GB. but during installation whole 500 GB is shown as free space...

Please help me.
I will really appreciate.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use gparted to check and set the partitions the way you want them.  Then proceed to run the Ubuntu installation choosing "Something else" as the option.  Now specify the partition that you have set aside for your Ubuntu installation.  Nothing else will be touched.  When the install complete it'll automatically update grub and identify all your OS installations and present them at your boot menu.

Comment: I used gparted in ubuntu but it says this error "dev/sda contains GPT signatures, indicating that it has a GPT table.  However, it does not have a valid fake msdos partition table, as it should.  Perhaps it was corrupted -- possibly by a program that doesn't understand GPT partition tables.  Or perhaps you deleted the GPT table, and are now using an msdos partition table.  Is this a GPT partition table? " when clicked on either options shows empty hard disk ?

Comment: Based on what you're describing it appears that you have lost your windows partition (it no longer exist).  Try searching for procedures for recovering a lost partition.  For a start, look at: http://askubuntu.com/questions/106306/how-to-recover-lost-partitions-data and http://askubuntu.com/questions/186193/deleted-partition-recovery.  Also look at (this google search): https://www.google.com/#q=ubuntu+recover+lost+partition

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this [tutorial](http://www.liberiangeek.net/2012/04/dual-boot-windows-7-and-ubuntu-12-04-precise-pangolin/) will help you. It describes step by step how to install Ubuntu 12.04 alongside Windows 7.

Have a nice day :)

Btw, 
this is my partition table for dual boot Ubuntu 14.04 and Windows 7:
[image]

Comment: Thanks for prompt reply, but when selected "something else" it shows Hard disk (500 GB) free. no partitions shown...this is only problem..

Comment: Can you explain how did you install Windows 8: what partiotions were created on the "Where do you want to install Windows?" page?