# How to reverse my formatted ubuntu partition?

Tags: partitioning

I have a dual boot system (Windows 10 + Ubuntu)

Today I plugged in my USB in haste and Windows 10 showed me a message to format, I thought this message was for my USB so I clicked formatted but later I found out that windows formatted the partition where my actual Ubuntu was residing.

Now I am pretty much clueless what to do and I want to know if there's some way I can reverse this formatting?

Thanks!

Comment: There's no way to reverse. There are ways to recover files but results vary and depend on what actually happened. Is your Ubuntu also in a USB drive? If not Windows would offer such a thing. Perhaps you could [edit] and describe with more detail?

Comment: @MichaelBay actually ubuntu is installed on my HDD and it was showing as a drive on my windows, I think when I mistakenly clicked my Ubuntu partition on windows thinking that I clicked my usb, that format message opened and I formatted my dive thinking it was my USB...

Comment: If that was a "quick format" Windows performed, you can probably recover most of your files.  A full format, which rewrites everything, no recovery of anything likely.

Comment: Related (but not necessarily a duplicate): [How to recover lost partitions data?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/106306/how-to-recover-lost-partitions-data)