# Losing all of my files suddenly

Tags: crash, data-loss

So a very strange just happened, I wanted to eject my usb, I got a message that a some program is using the USB and I must wait, I ignored it and continued ejecting the USB like I always do (I definitely shouldn't). After some messages started popping up and the theme of the ubuntu xfce changed to default and all my files were lost, just like that, the hard disk was wiped clean.

here is a snippet of the log file : [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/raw/gnNmTjuk)

I lost very important files, any help will be most welcomed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to recover lost partitions data?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/106306/how-to-recover-lost-partitions-data)

Comment: What were you using the USB for?

Comment: Issue with FAT occurred because the file system was heavily corrupt. You should regularly check file systems. Unlikely that your home folder has been wiped because of an issue with the USB. What happens if you restart the system? Does the system not boot anymore? Or do you get to the log in screen, but you cannot login? Load a live USB and mount your internal hard drive. I am quite sure you will see your home folder and your files.

Comment: The usb was used just to copy a file (PDF). just a regular usage.

Comment: You should also think about a backup strategy. The most easy way to restore lost files is to restore from backup. If a file is important, you always should have a copy on a different medium (drive, cloud).

Comment: after a restart, the system starts normaly, without any errors or any message, but without any files, even when using df -h the hard disk does from 50% usage to 6%

Comment: unfortunately I don't have any backup right now, from now on I certainly will back up mu files on regular basis.