# Simple way to recover a deleted file in a sub-dir of an encrypted home directory (ext4 file-system)

Tags: encryption, data-recovery, ext4, restore, undelete

I need a simple way to do it, such as one command or program to which:

1. specify the directory the file was in
2. ask for the list of the recoverable files found
3. specify which files have to be undeleted
4. specify the output directory where the file shall be recovered
5. a "start recovery" command

As outlined in the title, the deleted file is in a sub directory of my /home/username/Desktop/ directory, and the whole /home/username directory content is encrypted as chosen during Ubuntu 13.04 installation. I'm currently and regularly logged in. The file system is ext4.

Thank you very much, have a good day.

Andrew

Answer (score 0):

There are numerous tools to do the job. I have very good experience with `photorec` (ubuntu package `testdisk`), but have no idea how it will perform with an encrypted disk.

Take a look at [this page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DataRecovery), [this page](http://www.linux.com/news/enterprise/storage/8257-how-to-recover-lost-files-after-you-accidentally-wipe-your-hard-drive) and [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/31450/tool-for-recovering-deleted-data-from-a-flash-drive), but frankly, I would not have too high hopes. What can I say -- sorry for lecturing you, but you really should have made backups. Nowadays backups are easy and cheap, and really not such an effort to make. You know what they say -- there are two kinds of people: those who do their backups regularly and those who *will*.

Comment: Thank you January for the answer. I think that making a copy image of a 15 GB directory to undelete a single file of 100 KB is rather excessive. :-) I hope for something simpler.

Comment: Some times you have to do, what you have to do.

Comment: Depends how much you want that file, and how much time and money would it cost you to get it back.