# Regaining access to old External HDD (exfat/Mac&Win, maybe), unallocated maybe toasted HDD

Tags: hard-drive, mac, data-recovery, exfat

First off, I'm new to Ubuntu, and do not speak really comprehend too much of computer literacy. And English is not my main language.

So... I have and old HDD from a friend, that she wants to regain access to after her cat might've dropped it and stoped working, at least on her Mac. She thinks HDD was first formated as exFat to access both Mac/Win, but not entirely sure. I'm running a liveCD for UBUNTU13, and after pluging the external HDD from a usb port (SATA), the disk spins, sounds fine, and vibrates, telling me that it might actually be possible to regain access, and the option of proffesional and expensive help opening it vacuum is not neccesary.

On fdisk -l it shows as follows:

```
Disk /dev/sdh: 3000.6 GB, 3000592982016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 364801 cylinders, total 5860533168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x2ef796f3

Disk /dev/sdh doesn't contain a valid partition table.
```

On gparted shows as Unallocated, and it seems to be practically impossible for me to get it to mount.

Its a 3TB Western Digital external hard drive.

Please, my friend has her entire life on that HDD (her fault, i know), but any help would be GREATLY appreciated. And please don't be rude; remeber, "it's just a ride".

Thanks, and great day!

Comment: Sic `testdisk` on that drive. See http://askubuntu.com/q/31450/158442